# WPF, C# and MVVM Exposing commands

Tags: mvvm, c#-4.0, binding

Hi all I'm trying to get to grips with using MVVM, but I'm having a hard time :(, firstly for my question, I'm using the code provide in [this MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) as a template for my learning.
My question is simple how do expose independent commands, in this case he has create a list of hyperlinks, but how do i create a single button that's fixed and does the same as the 'create new customer' link.
I created something like this(was added to the MainWindowViewModel.cs):

```
   public CommandViewModel exposedCommand
    {
        get
        {
             return new CommandViewModel(
              Strings.MainWindowViewModel_Command_CreateNewCustomer,
              new RelayCommand(param => this.CreateNewCustomer())
              );
        }
    }
```

and then in the xaml document i created a new button, this was added to the MainWindow.xaml

```
         <Button 
            Content="Button" 
            Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="6,303,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"
            Command="{Binding Path=exposedCommand}"
        />
```

I am not to sure if I'm missing something, or what I am where going wrong,
Soz if I sounding a bit naive I have only just started using MVVM and routed commands and so.
Oh another thing it does load the link it just doesn't create the tab, in other words if you would to add

```
Console.Writeline("HERE");
```

to the exposedCommand method 
It would print out 'HERE' it just won't do anything when you click the button. 
Thanks Any Help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XAML code is correct.
I also started off with Josh Smith's MVVM article.
Below is a stripped down example of how I implement Commands in my ViewModels:

```
public class ProjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Private variable for holding save command
    private RelayCommand _saveCommand;

    // Other fields here

    // Constructors and properties and stuff here

    // Command Property for Save button. Bind XAML to "SaveCommand"
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_saveCommand == null) // Init command on first get
                _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.SaveChanges(), param => this.CanSave);

            return _saveCommand;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called when save command is executed
    /// </summary>
    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        // Save logic here...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Predicate for determining if SaveCommand is enabled
    /// </summary>        
    private bool CanSave
    {
        get
        {
            return true; // Replace with SaveCommand predicate logic
        }
    }
}
```

If it still does not work, check you runtime output for BindingErrors. If there is a BindingError that implies that the View cannot find the SaveCommand, then your ViewModel is not correctly set to be the DataContext of the View. Let me know in the comments if this is the problem.

Comment: Hey Thanks man :) I got that part to work I've gpot another question tho alongs the lines or relaying command to other viewModels, how would I go about doing this? Could you tell me how I could create a seperate viewmodel that has a command that I want to relay to something like addnewcusotmer function, how would I do this, this ViewModel doesnt inherit WorkSpaceViewModel because It doesn't close. How would I do this, so that when you click the button thats part of the new ViewModel it adds a newcustomer tab to the workspace?

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't forget to mark as answer. :-)
I suggest you open a new question for what you asked in the comment above - it's hard to answer in a comment, as I can't post code blocks here, and as a seperate question thread it could also help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind command to only those objects that has an implementation of ICommand interface.

In your example you are binding with view model object.

Instead of this create a property in view model that is a type of RelayCommand and bind this with button.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that concerns me is your the code inside the getter of you property. You're returning a new object **EVERY TIME** the exposedCommand is accessed. That's not really recommended, you should store that in a backing property like so:

```
CommandViewModel _exposedCommand;
public CommandViewModel exposedCommand
{
  get
  {
     if (_exposedCommand == null)
     {
       _exposedCommand = new CommandViewModel(
       Strings.MainWindowViewModel_Command_CreateNewCustomer,
       new RelayCommand(param => this.CreateNewCustomer()));
     }
     return _exposedCommand;
  }
}
```

That being said the typical way to present your desired `ICommand` property is something like this:

```
RelayCommand _exposedCommand;
public ICommand exposedCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_exposedCommand == null)
            _exposedCommand= new RelayCommand(param => this.CreateNewCustomer());
        return _exposedCommand;
    }
}
```